# youtube direct lite playlists and auto-approval

Tags: youtube, youtube-api

After struggling with getting Ytd to work for a couple of days I'm about to dive into Youtube Direct Lite which looks much friendlier to set up.

My first question is about the playlist size limit. Once a playlist is full (200 videos?) what would happen with further video submissions? Would the oldest be dropped or is it just impossible to add any more, effectively breaking the widget for that playlist?

I expect I would need to use multiple playlists and manually make new playlists and widgets if there's a lot of videos, but is there a best practice kinda way to do this for a large number of videoslso?

Also, would it be possible to automate the submission approvals programmatically if there's a lot of videos or is this beyond the scope of ytd-lite.

Thought it's better to ask these questions now before starting the process of setting this up for my site. Ytd-lite looks like a great project.

thanks.

Answer (score 0):

from the Doc:

https://developers.google.com/youtube/2.0/developers_guide_protocol_playlists#Adding_a_playlist

*Note: Playlists contain a maximum of 200 videos. As such, you will not be able to add a video to a playlist that already contains that many videos.*

I dont'n try to force this situation but I expect an error.

I believe that to automate the submission approvals programmatically you can modify the source code of YouTube Direct Lite, and with a little logic in the server side of your app you can do what you want.